# best practice to handle access token expiry

Tags: windows-store-apps, access-token, c++-cx

This question is in reference with Windows Live Services. What would be the best practice to handle token expiry. There are three alternatives i have come up with: 
1) check token status before making an request and handle an expired token accordingly 
2) run a thread as soon as a user is logged in and make it sleep for around 3590 seconds and then re-log in automatically. 
3) catch the 'access_token_expired' exception and then prompt a silent log in.

Which of these would be the best alternative to use or are there better approach to handle a token expiry?

*A Windows live access token is valid for about an hour(always less than 3600 seconds).

Comment: Can you put a loop in any time you try and use it that handles the expiration and tries to login again?

Comment: yes, that's the third alternative in the question above